# MySQL weird behavior with UNION

Tags: mysql, union

I noticed very weird behavior in MySQL when using multiple unions with select having more than 16 columns. I found this problem in one complex query and simplified it just to reproduce a problem.
I created [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bPWj8TVT) to demonstrate the issue. It is really strange that 1st query is doing left shift of column values, can anyone explain why it is happening?

```
WITH test1
     AS (SELECT  1 AS a,  2 AS b,  3 AS c,  4 AS d,  5 AS e,
                 6 AS f,  7 AS g,  8 AS h,  9 AS i, 10 AS j,
                11 AS k, 12 AS l, 13 AS m, 14 AS n, 15 AS o,
                16 AS p, 17 AS q),
     test2
     AS (SELECT  1 AS a,  2 AS b,  3 AS c,  4 AS d,  5 AS e,
                 6 AS f,  7 AS g,  8 AS h,  9 AS i, 10 AS j,
                11 AS k, 12 AS l, 13 AS m, 14 AS n, 15 AS o,
                16 AS p, 17 AS q),
     unionTest
     AS (SELECT * FROM test1
         UNION
         SELECT * FROM test2) 
SELECT * FROM unionTest WHERE 1 = 2
UNION
SELECT * FROM unionTest WHERE 1 = 1;
```

Returns

| a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j | k | l | m | n | o | p | q |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 0 |

I tried the same thing in postgres and it works fine. I do not see any logical explanation why this does not work in MySQL. MySQL version is  8.0.28

Comment: do you differentiate between `union` and `union all`?

Comment: Looks like a bug in MySQL. MariaDB works fine, just like SQLite and several other databases.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/dOYjbSTf

Comment: @mrmcwolf not sure what you mean, but I just figured that if I put UNION ALL in unionTest query it works fine. Still, it seems like a bug in MySQL

Saw your latest dbFiddle comment after I wrote this comment :)

Comment: yes it is certainly a bug. This isn't a legitimate behavioural difference between the two

Comment: @Akina - The bug is where does the `2` in column `a` come from? etc

Comment: Oh, I miss this. Also 2nd CTE is excess... https://dbfiddle.uk/jQVOuqPo this looks like a bug really.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in mysql version 8.0.12 perhaps dbfiddle is buggy..and I note the dbfiddle version is 8.0.30

Comment: DB Fiddle says it is using 8.0.30 so maybe a newly introduced bug? 16 is a power of 2 and I imagine something is not allocating enough space for 17 columns somewhere

Comment: @jonhtra please add the result of select version(); on your server.

Comment: @P.Salmon Version is  8.0.28. Added this info in question too

Comment: So that still gives quite a long time range (between `2018-07-27` and `2022-01-18`) to [look for any relevant change](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/commits/8.0)

Comment: specifically the bug seems to have started in version 8.0.18 though